# Accessing Local Devices from Web Page/Application

Tags: silverlight

I am designing an application that requires me to access devices connected to the machine. We will have control of the machine, meaning control of the software and OS installed.

I know in the past one might suggest active-x controls, I was wondering is there a better solution? I have looked into Silverlight as an alternative, but not found much information supporting that design approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in theory, there's tcp support in Silverlight and so you could use that to talk to a local piece of software.  In reality, tcp won't connect to the local machine unless you're in debug mode.  So, that's a problem.

What people have been [doing](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/03/27/10291.aspx) is creating a local WCF service and communicating with that.  If you take this approach, don't forget to host up a cross-domain file as well.

I'd just add that if you can control what's on the client machine, WPF may be a much more straightforward answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of the client's machine, Silverlight will not be of much help since it is sandboxed. In fact browsers and plugins are so locked down, that I think you should change your approach (maybe deploy your own client app, instead of using a browser/web app?)